# Convert TCP timestamp to date

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark, unix-timestamp

I am capturing network traffic with Wireshark and want to figure out what is the value that the TCP protocol includes in Timestamp option when used since it doesn't seem to be the current time in my system.

One of the packets my (MacOS) system has just sent has a TSvalue equal to 1877111769, however this value is surprisingly in the future:

```
date -r 1877111769
Mon 25 Jun 2029 21:56:09 CEST
```

Am I using the right command to interpret the Timestamp values in TCP segments? What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!